# How to change encoding of read RSS XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, encoding, rss

I would like to create RSS for my favourite website, but the problem is that it's RSS XML contains first line which corrupts whole RSS when parsing.

I get this error:

`System does not support 'ISO-8859-2' encoding. Line 1, position 31.`

Code:

```
void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
      SyndicationFeed feed;
      try {
           using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result)) { 
               // I WOULD LIKE to delete some rows from the Result
               feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
               lista.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
            }
       } catch (WebException we) { 
            MessageBox.Show("The internet connection is down.");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the .NET framework used in WP7 doesn't support other encodings than `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1`. What you could do, is to generate your own encoding implementation using [this tool](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator).

Then you read the stream with a detour via a `StreamReader` using the custom encoding:

```
using ( StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(e.Result, new CustomEncoding()) )
using ( XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader) ) 
{ 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either try to re-encode the string that is in *e.Result*, perhaps by using the [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx) method in .NET. But this will probably not be enough since I assume that there is a encoding="ISO-8859-2" attribute in the xml-code. So you will probably also need to do a String.Replace that attribute with something else.

Or just try to replace the attribute with another one and see if that works. Do a e.Result.Replace("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8") and see what happens. If that doesn't work, try the first option of converting the strings encoding to another one and then to the replace.